# Get part of string before filename as directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, substring, token, delimiter

There are a list of images in a directory. I would like to create a bat file that just iterates all files, and based on the filename it orders them in directories with these rules, for e.g:

```
1812_1005541_5226_983_1B.tif
1812_1005541_5226_983_2B.tif
1812_1005541_5226_983_3B.tif
```

I would like the result to be each moved to:

```
1812_1005541_5226_983 / 1812_1005541_5226_983_1B.tif
1812_1005541_5226_983 / 1812_1005541_5226_983_2B.tif
1812_1005541_5226_983 / 1812_1005541_5226_983_3B.tif
```

Which means that I would like to get the first 4 parts of the string by delimiter "_". 
This is the code, can you suggest me a change here to achive the above result?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg *.tif) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1,5 delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file? Why?

Comment: Yes, it must be a bat file unfortunately!

Comment: You do not need the first two `FOR /F` commands to get the file name and file extension.  You already have access to them with the `%%A` token. `set fname=%%~nA` & `set fextn=%%~xA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you basically have to change just your method to get the folder (looks a bit complicated, but has the advantage of no fixed tokens; takes all elements except the last one. So : `1812_1005541_5226_983_1B.tif` will become `1812_1005541_5226_983` and `1945_2008835_5X.tif` will become `1945_2008835`

```
break>1812_1005541_5226_983_1B.tif
break>1812_1005541_5226_983_2B.tif
break>1812_1005541_5226_983_3B.tif
break>1945_2008835_5X.tif 

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg *.tif) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   REM for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC

   for  %%D in ("X:!fname:_=\!") do set folname=%%~pD
   set "folname=!folname:\=_!"
   set "folname=!folname:~1,-1!"

   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
tree /f
pause
```

`for /f %%D in ("!fname:_=\!") do set folname=%%~pD` replaces each `_` with a `\`, then gets the "path" (`%%~pD`), removing the last element. Then change back `\` to `_` and remove the first and last character (remainders of the way to process it as a path)

(the `break` lines are just to generate a few files for testing)

Comment: Shouldn't this line `for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%~nB") do set fextn=%%~xC` be using `%%A`. The token `%%B` no longer exists. Regardless of that, the `FOR /F` is not needed to get the base file name or extension into a variable.

Comment: @Squashman: you are right. Doesn't matter, as `fextn` is never used.